# Split list of dictionaries into multiple list of dictionaries by its value in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I wanted to split a list of dictionaries into multiple list of dictionaries based on the value of a particular key dynamically.

```
Actual_list = [{status:Pass,name:abc,loop_count:1},{status:Fail,name:abc,loop_count:1},{status:Fail,name:abc,loop_count:2},{status:Fail,name:abc,loop_count:2},]
```

Here the list of dictionaries holds values, which has to be split according to the key-value of loop_count. Each splitter list of dictionaries should hold unique value of loop_count

```
Expected_list =[ [{status:Pass,name:abc,loop_count:1}, {status:Fail,name:abc,loop_count:2}],[{status:Fail,name:abc,loop_count:1},{status:Fail,name:abc,loop_count:2}]]
```

Comment: How do you know which `loop_count`s should go together?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and get some tips on [ask], so you can get the better results from this community. You would need to provide a [mcve] with your best effort attempting to solve the issue, and we can help from where you got stuck.

Comment: Based on the occurrence of loop_count, the first occurrence of unique loop_count (1,n) has to be grouped together and the next occurrence (1,n) has to be another list of dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```py
from itertools import groupby


Actual_list = [
    {"status": "Pass", "name": "abc", "loop_count": 1},
    {"status": "Pass", "name": "abc", "loop_count": 1},
    {"status": "Fail", "name": "abc", "loop_count": 1},
    {"status": "Fail", "name": "abc", "loop_count": 2},
    {"status": "Fail", "name": "abc", "loop_count": 2},
]

nums, vals = [], {}
for k, g in groupby(
    sorted(Actual_list, key=lambda k: k["loop_count"]),
    lambda k: k["loop_count"],
):
    vals[k] = list(g)
    nums.append(k)

out = []
while any(vals.values()):
    out.append([vals[n].pop(0) for n in nums if vals[n]])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    [
        {"status": "Pass", "name": "abc", "loop_count": 1},
        {"status": "Fail", "name": "abc", "loop_count": 2},
    ],
    [
        {"status": "Pass", "name": "abc", "loop_count": 1},
        {"status": "Fail", "name": "abc", "loop_count": 2},
    ],
    [{"status": "Fail", "name": "abc", "loop_count": 1}],
]
```